# Does going prone break a grapple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, prone

If two medium creatures are in a grapple with one another, will an effect that causes one of the grapplers to go prone end the grapple?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Grappled and Prone are different conditions, independent of each other. Tripping a character while it is grappling just means it is prone and grappling instead, with all the penalties and bonuses that entails.

Answer (score 4):

No. That would have to be specified in the rules, and it isn't.

Comment: There's nothing that says you can't trip a grappled opponent, therefore you can.